# Clear WinInet DNS cache programmatically

Tags: caching, dns, httprequest, wininet

WinINet library caches IP address for any URL accessed over it. Because of this, when IP address for that URL gets changed then also WinInet library's `HttpSendRequest` goes to older IP address.

And, if older IP is responding, then WinINet will send all http request to older IP only.

Is there any way to force clean DNS cache of WinInet?

Or

Is there any way to force  WinINet to send HTTP request to specified IP address (as we are able to get newer IP using `gethostbyname()`)?

Note :

1. [gethostbyname](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms738524%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is giving me newer IP address, So this behaviour is happening of WinINet's caching.
2. I have tried "method 2" suggested in [this MS article](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/263558), but it didn't help
3. [Sample code](http://codepad.org/ga7xA4nL)

Comment: It's kind of ghetto, but can you spawn a separate process?  Here's the command line: `ipconfig /flushdns`

Comment: @Tom `ipconfig /flushdns` flushes system DNS cache only. But WinInet maintains its own DNS cache which can't be cleared with this command.

Comment: I did not know that!  My apologies, good luck

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try to use the [flag](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa383661%28v=vs.85%29.aspx#INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE) when connecting:

> INTERNET_FLAG_DONT_CACHE = 0x04000000 Does not add the returned entity
>   to the cache. This is identical to the preferred value,
>   INTERNET_FLAG_NO_CACHE_WRITE.

Or you can take a look at the DeleteUrlCacheEntry from the WinInet documentation [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa385473%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

I beleave this should do the trick.

**--UPDATE**

From [this doc](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa384233%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) I've seen that there is an better flag to use it, look at the:

> INTERNET_FLAG_PRAGMA_NOCACHE
>   Forces the request to be resolved by the origin server, even if a cached copy exists on the proxy.

**--UPDATE**

As tested by @Pradeep you can change this registry keys to work it:
HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\DnsCacheEnabled
ServerInfoTimeOut and DnsCacheTimeout to 0.

Comment: Did you try the DeleteUrlCacheEntry ?

Comment: It seens that wininet.dll reads the registry key DnsCacheEnabled from: 
SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache          

and

SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings\5.0\Cache  

using Security_HKLM_only

Comment: I don't see WinInet using any key with DnsCacheEnabled in its path. It will be helpful, if you point to any documentation mentioning this.

Comment: I've seen this using PE Explorer, sorry I forget to say that.

Comment: `DnsCacheEnabled` is present in `HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings`. But for making this work I also have to set `ServerInfoTimeOut` and `DnsCacheTimeout` to `0`.
Thanks for your help. Can you modify your answer, so I can accept it?